# Downloading all files from a FTP directory, running into problems with escaping spaces

Tags: maven, apache-camel

I have my camel configured to download all files from a specific FTP directory. Now this is all easy enough and everything seems to be working fine. However, I am running into errors when the files contain a space in their names such as *File 123.csv*. I know I could specifically target the files with an escape character. The only difficulty is that these files are dynamic in nature and change daily, so I will not know which files may or may not have spaces. 
I figure I can just read all the file URI and make adjustments from there. But I was wondering if there is any Camel specific way to handle this.

Errors: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in path at index 60: hdfs://test.net/user/CamelTests/File Layout.csv`

```
GenericFileOnCompletion        - Rollback file strategy: org.apache.camel.component.file.strategy.GenericFileRenameProcessStrategy@fe8d1b for file: RemoteFile[File Layout.csv]
```

Camel Code

```
from("{{ftp.serverLP}}/Memo/Loss?username=ftp&password=pass")
    .to("hdfs2://Test.net/user/CamelTests/?fileSystemType=HDFS")
    .log("Downloaded file ${file:name} complete.");
```

Comment: Would it be possible to post a snippet of the camel configuration (for the camel ftp plugin) ?

Comment: Added the camel snippet. Please let me know if you need more @AshutoshJindal

Comment: Hmm, thanks. I was wondering if it's the problem in the way camel handles a specific file system? Would it be possible to investigate what happens if you change the `.to(..)` to use a non-HDFS file system ? The error posted seems to indicate a problem with the destination to which the files are being copied (HDFS), not the FTP source.

Comment: Thats it! Its somekind of HDFS error.. Thank you so much @AshutoshJindal

Comment: Is it worth up voting / accepting the correct answer (below)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the `.to(..)` to use a non-HDFS file system.

The error posted seems to indicate a problem with the destination to which the files are being copied (HDFS), not the FTP source.